# Garbage collection of java Runnable

Tags: java, garbage-collection, runnable

I have Singleton Service which is collecting data based on events occuring in the System. I am collecting this data and store them in a `HashMap` which is a member variable of this Singleton Service. After every 5 mins I need to write the collected data to disk.

For this I am executing a Runnable task. Since I cannot pass a parameter to java 'run()' method ,

I created my worker like below :

```
FiveMinuteWorker fiveMinTask = new FiveMinuteWorker(hashMap);// hashMap of this singleton service.
```

I execute the runnable as below :

```
ScheduledFuture<?> fiveMinTask = fScheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
                fiveMinWorker, initialDelay, 5 * 60 * 1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS
        );
```

I have 2 questions.

When the `Runnable` 'runs' I cache the data in `hashMap` to disk, will it be garbage collected after it runs or will the reference hang around because they hold reference of the `HashMap` from Singleton Service which will remain forever ?

In the `Runnable` After the `HashMap` is cached to disk I can clear its contents which will effectively clear the contents from the Singleton Service `hashMap` right since its the same reference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"will *it* be garbage collected after it runs or will the reference hang around because *they* hold reference of the HashMap"_  What is the first "it"?  What is "they"

Comment: It will not be gc'ed because you are working on the same instance and your Service still holds a reference to the map. If you clear the map at the end, its entries will be gc'ed (if there are no other references to them). There is no guarentee that they will be gc'ed immediately. That will depend on the GC implementation of the java you are using.

Comment: Sidenote: Why "5 * 60 *1000" and "TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS" instead of "5" and "TimeUnit.MINUTES" ?

Comment: sorry i was not clear, 'it' meant the runnables. Will the runnable I am creating every 5 minutes be garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

scheduleWithFixedDelay() function is not creating new instance of the fiveMinWorker every time it runs. It uses the same instance each time it runs after the period you have set. So basically there will always be only one instance of the fiveMinWorker no mater how many times the task is run.